# Ruby - Handling JSON hash when key may not exist

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, I'd like to know how best to handle getting a variable from a json hash and then proceeding only if it exists, else raise an error.

So here is some example code:

```
digest = cover_id(map)

def cover_id(a_map)
   cover_from_map = a_map['metadata']['cover'][0]['@']
   a_map['resources'].find {|resource| resource['id']==cover_from_map}['-major-md5-digest']
end
```

Looking at this there are 2 things I'm not clear how best to handle:

- If firstly `song_map['metadata']['cover'][0]['@']` did not exist - is it just a case of using `song_map.key?(['metadata']['cover'][0]['@'])`. I feel using this means I've duplicated code?
- Instead of hardcoding that 0 is there any way I can just say get the first?

Basically, from what I know now, I was thinking:

```
digest = cover_id(map) rescue nil

def cover_id(a_map)
   unless a_map['metadata']['cover'][0]['@'] return nil

   cover_from_map = a_map['metadata']['cover'][0]['@']
   a_map['resources'].find {|resource| resource['id']==cover_from_map}['-major-md5-digest']
end
```

But I dont think that would handle if `a_map['metadata']['cover'][0]['@']` didn't actually exist.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check method `dig` of Hash:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot)                 #=> nil
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: 1.9.3 is officially dead as of 2015/02/23 (i.e. you're running a 4-year-old zombie). I'd strongly urge you to upgrade.